# Override single route in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes

How can I override a single route in Symfony2?

I have a bundle that comes with a **`bundle_routing.yml`** file.
In a bundle that extends this parent bundle i also have routing file:
**`routing.xml`**
Note that the files are named different.

In this routing file I like to override a single parent route.
I tried to simple redeclare it and change the pattern.
But it's not applied.

parent:

```
MyParentBundle_detailpage:
    pattern:  /detail
    defaults: { _controller: "MyParentBundle:Item:detail" }
```

child:

```
<route id="MyParentBundle_detailpage" pattern="/itemDetails">
        <default key="_controller">MyParentBundle:Item:detail</default>
</route>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the reason myself:
Its because of the import order in the main routing file.

```
app/config/routing.yml
```

The parent routing must be imported first and the routing of the child bundle must be imported second.

```
MyParentBundle:
    resource: "@MyParentBundle/Resources/config/bundle_routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
MyChildBundle:
    resource: "@MyChildBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to import the child last? Because for as far i know symfony2 takes the first matching route, which should now be the parent route.

Comment: @MatsRietdijk Symfony takes first matching route, but from collected ones. If you define route on the same index only last is available.