# How to override route in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.3

It's not a duplicate of [override single route in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270484/override-single-route-in-symfony2). Please be patient and read my question carefully.

My problem is differs from the question above.
So, my Symfony app has a standard structure. BUT it's configured in a specific way.

- app/config/routing.yml contains several bundles routes, for example :

  ```
  _project_custom1:
      resource: "@ProjectCustom1Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
      prefix:   /custom1
  _project_custom2:
      resource: "@ProjectCustom2Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
      prefix:   /custom2
  ```
- **src/** directory has two bundles and next structure, e.g.

  `Common/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`
  `Common/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing_dashboard.yml`

  `routing.yml` contains next lines:

  `admin_dashboard_content:
  resource: "@CommonAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing_dashboard.yml"
  prefix:   /dashboard`

  `routing_dashboard.yml` contains:

  `admin_dashboard_license_content:
  path:     /license-content
  defaults: { _controller: CommonAdminBundle:Dashboard:licenseContent }`

Next bundle is Custom bundle. How can extend `DashboardController`,  override `licenseContentAction` and override only one (`/license-content`) route and make Symfony use my Custom bundle configuration?

Copying the same structure is not working.
According to my explanation I wrote something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Custom1\Controller;
use Common\AdminBundle\Controller\DashboardController as BaseController;
class DashboardController extends BaseController
{
    public function licenseContentAction()
    {
       //return parent::licenseContentAction();
       die("HELLO!");
    }
}
```

How I can build route file for make extended method working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add these lines into the `app/config/routing.yml` file.

```
admin_dashboard_license_content:
    path: /dashboard/license-content
    defaults: { _controller: CustomBundle:Dashboard:licenseContent }
```

And create a `DashboardController` extending the base Symfony controller with a `licenseContentAction` method into the `CustomBundle` namespace.

**And now the magic...**

If you want to preserve the path, you have to add these lines at the beginning of the `routing.yml` file. The name of the route has to be different (unique) and the path of course has to be same as the overrode one.

*The Symfony looks for the path and immediately when it matches the request is redirected to the corresponding controller action.*

If you want to change the path add these lines at the end of the `routing.yml` file. The name of the route has to be same. I'm not sure if the previously defined route (path) still exists, I suppose yes, and if requests, made with this path, are still processed...

*Symfony collects the routes into an array where the key is the name of a route. By adding a route with same name at the end of the file a previously defined route is overrode.*